# how do i change color of label in wpf using vb

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm converting an application from winforms to wpf and the app changes the color of some labels. In winforms you'd use lblName.ForeColor = Color.Red. But in WPF the Color.Red isn't correct. I can't seem to find the WPF version of this. Most of the sites I can find use C# instead of VB.

The XAML code for a label that needs to change color:

```
<Label x:Name="lblMsg" Content="Label4" Foreground="Red" Margin="34,562,542.4,71.8"/>
```

The VB code that should change the color of this label:

```
 lblMsg.Foreground = Color.Green
```

Comment: Note that the "WPF way" to do things is to avoid setting things in code and do it through data binding and triggers in XAML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution for your problem:

```
lblMsg.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
```

or

```
lblMsg.Foreground = Brushes.Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out at last.
this:

```
lblMsg.Foreground = Color.Green
```

should be this:

```
lblMsg.Foreground = Brushes.Green
```